# How pathological can a Laplace transform be?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, singularity, branch-cuts, inverse-laplace

Almost every treatment of the Laplace transform that I come across talks about "the poles" of the Laplace transform function $F(s)$, thereby seeming to implicitly assume that $F(s)$ is meromorphic on the complex plane.

Can a Laplace transform function contain essential singularities, branch cuts, or other, more complicated ways to fail to be analytic? If so, are there any simple examples of such Laplace transforms? Does the usual inverse Laplace transform still work in these cases?

Comment: $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$?

Comment: not sure what exactly you ask as any power series convergent on the unit disc $\sum a_nz^n$ becomes a (very simple) Laplace transform on $\Re s >0$ when you put $z=e^{-s}$ so its analytic extension or lack thereof to $\Re s \le 0$ is the same as the analytic extension or lack of it of the power series to the exterior of the unit disc - for example if you take an algebraic function like $\sqrt {1-z}$ it becomes $\sqrt {1-e^{-s}}$ which has branch points where $e^{s}=1$ and so on;

Comment: Yes, a LT can have branch points.